# Oracle - Suggestion sought on populating a look up table

Tags: oracle, plsql

Converting a legacy system over to a current Oracle system, and seeking suggestions to condense data from 4 tables, into a look-up table. Current process entails a mix of java and PL scripts to populate this table, which is far too complex, making maintenance painful. Looking to simplify populating this table.

Any suggestions would be helpful

```
CREATE TABLE LOOKUP_CODE
(
  CREATED_DATE   DATE         NOT NULL,
  CODE           NUMBER(16)   NOT NULL,
  REG_KEY        NUMBER(12)   NOT NULL,
  OPR_KEY        NUMBER(12)   NOT NULL,
  VMS_KEY        NUMBER(12)   NOT NULL,
  APR_KEY        NUMBER(12)   NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE REG
(
  KEY            NUMBER(12)   NOT NULL,
  CODE_START     NUMBER(16)   NOT NULL,
  CODE_END       NUMBER(16)   NOT NULL,
  CREATED_BY     VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
  CREATED_DATE   DATE         NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO REG VALUES (1213, 1000, 1010, 'Alchemy', TO_DATE('12/2/2016 4:17:13 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'));
INSERT INTO REG VALUES (1317, 2000, 2200, 'Alchemy', TO_DATE('12/5/2016 7:21:37 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'));
INSERT INTO REG VALUES (1387, 2400, 2600, 'Alchemy', TO_DATE('12/3/2016 6:22:18 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'));


CREATE TABLE OPR
(
  KEY            NUMBER(12)   NOT NULL,
  CODE_START     NUMBER(16)   NOT NULL,
  CODE_END       NUMBER(16)   NOT NULL,
  CREATED_BY     VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
  CREATED_DATE   DATE         NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO OPR VALUES (5617, 1000, 1010, 'Alchemy', TO_DATE('12/2/2016 6:21:53 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'));
INSERT INTO OPR VALUES (8112, 2400, 2600, 'Alchemy', TO_DATE('12/2/2016 11:57:03 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'));

CREATE TABLE VMS
(
  KEY            NUMBER(12)   NOT NULL,
  CODE_START     NUMBER(16)   NOT NULL,
  CODE_END       NUMBER(16)   NOT NULL,
  CREATED_BY     VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
  CREATED_DT   DATE         NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO VMS VALUES (1213, 1000, 1010, 'Alchemy', TO_DATE('12/2/2016 2:28:24 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'));
INSERT INTO VMS VALUES (1317, 2000, 2200, 'Alchemy', TO_DATE('12/6/2016 1:07:37 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'));


CREATE TABLE APR
(
  KEY            NUMBER(12)   NOT NULL,
  CODE_START     NUMBER(16)   NOT NULL,
  CODE_END       NUMBER(16)   NOT NULL,
  CREATED_BY     VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
  CREATED_DT   DATE         NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO APR VALUES (12103, 1000, 1010, 'Alchemy', TO_DATE('12/2/2016 4:17:13 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'));
INSERT INTO APR VALUES (13117, 2000, 2200, 'Admin', TO_DATE('12/3/2016 3:31:27 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'));
INSERT INTO APR VALUES (13118, 2400, 2600, 'Alchemy', TO_DATE('12/3/2016 3:34:41 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'));


Example of content from REG
KEY     CODE_START     CODE_END     CREATED_BY     CREATED_DT
10057    12300          12375        Jeff           12/4/2016
10058    15000          15100        Aaron          12/3/2016

OPR Table
KEY     CODE_START     CODE_END     CREATED_BY     CREATED_DT
8712     12300          12375        Jeff           12/5/2016

VMS Table
KEY     CODE_START     CODE_END     CREATED_BY     CREATED_DT
12752    15000          15100        Aaron          12/4/2016

APR Table
KEY     CODE_START     CODE_END     CREATED_BY     CREATED_DT
7618     12300          12375        Jeff           12/2/2016
7620     15000          15100        Aaron          12/4/2016

Expected output for the lookup table
CREATED_DATE    CODE    REG_KEY   OPR_KEY    VMS_KEY    APR_KEY
12/2/2016       12300    10057     8712       -1         7618
12/2/2016       12301    10057     8712       -1         7618
12/2/2016       12302    10057     8712       -1         7618
...
12/2/2016       12375    10057     8712       -1         7618
12/3/2016       15000    10058     -1         12752      7620
12/3/2016       15000    10058     -1         12752      7620
...
12/3/2016       15100    10058     -1         12752      7620

Total number of rows in lookup table: 175 rows. I think it's 177, actually.
```

Comment: One suggestion, pre-populating the code won't work efficiently. The code can from up to 12 digits wide at this time, and will likely grow as demand increases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you've got going on is what most people would call a "lookup table" (even if you use it to look stuff up).  Anyway, what you might do is

(A) write a `SELECT` statement that expands `REG` rows into individual values of `CODE`.
(B) repeat (A) for the other tables - `OPR`, `VMS`, etc.
(C) write a `SELECT` that joins the 1st four `SELECT` statements by `CODE`.  That should give you all the rows that should be in the `LOOKUP_CODE` table.
(D) `DELETE` all the rows from `LOOKUP_CODE` and insert the results from (C)

Like this:

```
delete from lookup_code;

insert into lookup_code
WITH regcodes AS
       (SELECT r.key,
               r.code_start,
               r.code_end,
               c.code,
               r.created_by,
               r.created_date
        FROM   reg r
               CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT r.code_start + LEVEL - 1 code
                                   FROM   DUAL
                                   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= r.code_end - r.code_start + 1) c),
     oprcodes AS
       (SELECT r.key,
               r.code_start,
               r.code_end,
               c.code,
               r.created_by,
               r.created_date
        FROM   opr r
               CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT r.code_start + LEVEL - 1 code
                                   FROM   DUAL
                                   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= r.code_end - r.code_start + 1) c),
     vmscodes AS
       (SELECT r.key,
               r.code_start,
               r.code_end,
               c.code,
               r.created_by,
               r.created_dt created_date
        FROM   vms r
               CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT r.code_start + LEVEL - 1 code
                                   FROM   DUAL
                                   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= r.code_end - r.code_start + 1) c),
     aprcodes AS
       (SELECT r.key,
               r.code_start,
               r.code_end,
               c.code,
               r.created_by,
               r.created_dt created_date
        FROM   apr r
               CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT r.code_start + LEVEL - 1 code
                                   FROM   DUAL
                                   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= r.code_end - r.code_start + 1) c)
SELECT LEAST (NVL (r.created_date, TO_DATE ('31-DEC-4712', 'DD-MON-YYYY')),
              NVL (o.created_date, TO_DATE ('31-DEC-4712', 'DD-MON-YYYY')),
              NVL (v.created_date, TO_DATE ('31-DEC-4712', 'DD-MON-YYYY')),
              NVL (a.created_date, TO_DATE ('31-DEC-4712', 'DD-MON-YYYY')))
         created_date,
       COALESCE (r.code,
                 o.code,
                 v.code,
                 a.code)
         code,
       NVL (r.key, -1) reg_key,
       NVL (o.key, -1) opr_key,
       NVL (v.key, -1) vms_key,
       NVL (a.key, -1) apr_key
FROM   regcodes r
       FULL OUTER JOIN oprcodes o ON o.code = r.code
       FULL OUTER JOIN vmscodes v ON v.code = r.code
       FULL OUTER JOIN aprcodes a ON a.code = r.code;
```

#### Pre-12c Syntax

```
WITH regcodes AS
       (SELECT r.key,
               r.code_start,
               r.code_end,
               r.code_start + c.rn - 1 code,
               r.created_by,
               r.created_date
        FROM   reg r
               INNER JOIN (SELECT ROWNUM rn
                           FROM   DUAL
                           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT MAX (code_end - code_start + 1) FROM reg)) c
                 ON r.code_start + c.rn - 1 BETWEEN r.code_start AND r.code_end),
     oprcodes AS
       (SELECT r.key,
               r.code_start,
               r.code_end,
               r.code_start + c.rn - 1 code,
               r.created_by,
               r.created_date
        FROM   opr r
               INNER JOIN (SELECT ROWNUM rn
                           FROM   DUAL
                           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT MAX (code_end - code_start + 1) FROM opr)) c
                 ON r.code_start + c.rn - 1 BETWEEN r.code_start AND r.code_end),
     vmscodes AS
       (SELECT r.key,
               r.code_start,
               r.code_end,
               r.code_start + c.rn - 1 code,
               r.created_by,
               r.created_dt created_date
        FROM   vms r
               INNER JOIN (SELECT ROWNUM rn
                           FROM   DUAL
                           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT MAX (code_end - code_start + 1) FROM vms)) c
                 ON r.code_start + c.rn - 1 BETWEEN r.code_start AND r.code_end),
     aprcodes AS
       (SELECT r.key,
               r.code_start,
               r.code_end,
               r.code_start + c.rn - 1 code,
               r.created_by,
               r.created_dt created_date
        FROM   apr r
               INNER JOIN (SELECT ROWNUM rn
                           FROM   DUAL
                           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT MAX (code_end - code_start + 1) FROM apr)) c
                 ON r.code_start + c.rn - 1 BETWEEN r.code_start AND r.code_end)
SELECT LEAST (NVL (r.created_date, TO_DATE ('31-DEC-4712', 'DD-MON-YYYY')),
              NVL (o.created_date, TO_DATE ('31-DEC-4712', 'DD-MON-YYYY')),
              NVL (v.created_date, TO_DATE ('31-DEC-4712', 'DD-MON-YYYY')),
              NVL (a.created_date, TO_DATE ('31-DEC-4712', 'DD-MON-YYYY')))
         created_date,
       COALESCE (r.code,
                 o.code,
                 v.code,
                 a.code)
         code,
       NVL (r.key, -1) reg_key,
       NVL (o.key, -1) opr_key,
       NVL (v.key, -1) vms_key,
       NVL (a.key, -1) apr_key
FROM   regcodes r
       FULL OUTER JOIN oprcodes o ON o.code = r.code
       FULL OUTER JOIN vmscodes v ON v.code = r.code
       FULL OUTER JOIN aprcodes a ON a.code = r.code;
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew.  Yes, I would be using an insert to populate the table.
I'm playing with a function to produce the range of values, and tying my table data elements. But so far, it's not working.  This 4 step would handle the problem.

Comment: So far, my attempts have all failed.  I can get a list of numbers from the included start and end, but I'm not finding a way to tie it to the main table. 
Once more Oracle is frustrating me to no end.

Comment: Matthew, I have updated with insert statements for the base tables. Thank you!

Comment: I have found a non-optimal solution. Call a Java package that will read the data table, create my list object, then write it to the Oracle table. No external PL or Oracle needed.  But now, it's not part of the project and is an external component.  But it works.

Comment: I'll send you a `MERGE` statement tomorrow, if no one else beats me to it.

Comment: Was able to create a script using an outer and inner cursor. Not very efficient, but it populates my table.

Comment: Added code for steps A-C, which will give you the data that you want to end up in `LOOKUP_CODES`.  Could you just `DELETE FROM LOOKUP_CODES` and `INSERT` the results of this query?  What is your logic for maintaining `LOOKUP_CODES.CREATED_DATE`?

Comment: By the way, I got 413 lookup rows, which is more than you suggested.  I must not be understanding your requirements correctly.

Comment: My math says 213 rows should be the result in the lookup, based on the provided data. For CREATED_DATE, this is just the MIN(CREATED_DATE) from the 4 tables.

Comment: Matthew - Thank you.  I'm also getting 413 rows back.  I'm walking through the resultset and see if I can find the issue.  Thanks for the suggestion and code.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your explanation of how to handle `CREATED_DATE`.

Comment: I have show-horned this into my project, but it doesn't run. It's complaining about ORA-00907: missing right paranthesis
I have matched the code completely, something seems out of sync.

Comment: Might be the `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` syntax -- it requires Oracle 12c.  What version are you on?

Comment: 11g - That would explain it

Comment: Run a section, no issues with the pre-12c version.  It's been folded in and running it now.  Hoping to see results very soon.
Thank you so much for the added assistance

Comment: Sad news, it fails running out of memory after 30 minutes.  However, this works and I will get it tweaked.  Many thanks, Matthew.

Comment: Do you have very large `CODE` ranges in the 4 tables?  An alternate way of generating the rows (other than `CONNECT BY`) might avoid your memory issues. You might consider posting the memory error on another question if you are stumped.  Good luck.

Comment: Currently they extend to 8 digits.  I have a couple ideas based on what you presented and what I had learned prior.
Thank you!

Comment: I've been working on this over the weekend, and have found no working solution in Oracle. Matthew, I was unable to get your code to work on only 1 table, let alone all 4. It simply chews up too much memory. I also attempted to utilize an inner/outer cursor with bulk loading, but it runs for hours. It appears I have hit a wall with Oracle.

Comment: The memory consumption is likely the `CONNECT BY`, if you have very large ranges in the 4 tables.  I'll send a variant that uses less memory later today.

Comment: Nods - I'm certain it is.  Your code works great.  The issue at hand is the size. Due to the ranges, the code was converting ~2,580 rows into ~141 million.  The ranges from 4-7 digits were in the millions of records. I'm now looking at a method of recognizing the range as a key, instead of breaking out each code.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be more complex than I expected.  The best way I found was to create a function, which returns a range of values, and run this inside a procedure which uses an outer and inner cursor. The outer cursor gathers my start and end values, plus the key and the created date. The start and end are feed to the function, which produces the range, and an insert statement to load into the database.  The final step, which I haven't written is a simple query to join the 4 tables together, based on the code.  This is obvious, so I didn't include in the solution below.  The procedure needs to be created for each of the base tables. Then a final script/procedure that performs the left joins on the four tables where things match.

```
DROP TYPE CODE_CONTAINER;
DROP TYPE CODE_TYPE;

CREATE TYPE CODE_TYPE AS OBJECT 
(
  CODE NUMBER
);
/

CREATE TYPE CODE_CONTAINER AS TABLE OF CODE_TYPE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_CODE_RANGE(MY_START IN PLS_INTEGER, MY_END IN PLS_INTEGER)
    RETURN CODE_CONTAINER
    PIPELINED
IS
    OUT_REC CODE_TYPE := CODE_TYPE(NULL);

BEGIN
  FOR i IN MY_START .. MY_END LOOP
    OUT_REC.CODE := i;

    PIPE ROW(OUT_REC);
  END LOOP;

END GET_CODE_RANGE;
/
```

This is the script that populates one of the four tables

```
DECLARE

  TYPE CURSOR_TYPE IS REF CURSOR;
  REG_CURSOR CURSOR_TYPE;
  CODE_CURSOR CURSOR_TYPE;
  REG_KEY_VALUE REG.REG_KEY%TYPE;
  BEGIN_VALUE REG.BEGIN_CODE%TYPE;
  END_VALUE REG.END_CODE%TYPE;
  CODE_VALUE REG.END_CODE%TYPE;
  WHO_VALUE REG.CREATED_BY%TYPE;
  CREATED_VALUE REG.CREATED_DATE%TYPE;
  CODE REG.BEGIN_CODE%TYPE;

BEGIN

        OPEN REG_CURSOR FOR SELECT REG_KEY, CODE_START, CODE_END, CREATED_DATE, CREATED_BY 
                            FROM REG
                            WHERE CODE_START <> CODE_END;
            LOOP
                FETCH REG_CURSOR INTO REG_KEY_VALUE, BEGIN_VALUE, END_VALUE, CREATED_VALUE, WHO_VALUE;
                EXIT WHEN REG_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;

                OPEN CODE_CURSOR FOR SELECT CODE FROM TABLE(GET_CODE_RANGE(BEGIN_VALUE, END_VALUE));
                    LOOP
                        FETCH CODE_CURSOR INTO CODE_VALUE;
                        EXIT WHEN CODE_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;

                        INSERT INTO REG_HIST (REG_KEY, CODE, CREATED_DATE, CREATED_BY) 
                        VALUES(REG_KEY_VALUE, CODE_VALUE, CREATED_VALUE, WHO_VALUE);
                    END LOOP;
                    COMMIT;
                CLOSE CODE_CURSOR;
            END LOOP;
        CLOSE REG_CURSOR;
END;
/
```

Comment: Using the cursor is significantly slow.  To process ~2000 records, which generate 12.4 million rows takes nearly 6 minutes to complete, for a single table. This equates to 30 minutes to generate this list.  Need to make this run much faster.

Comment: This approach assumes the every value of `CODE` is in one of the ranges given in the `REG` table.  As I read the requirements, not every code is in every one of the 4 tables (in which case the corresponding `xxx_KEY` column in `LOOKUP_CODE` is -1).  If there can be `LOOKUP_CODE` entries with `REG_KEY`=-1, this approach doesn't work, I think.